# How do we get logs on read queries from delta lake in Databricks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Delta lake has transaction logs that contain information on the writes happening at deltalake. Is there some kind of audit logs for reading queries happening on Deltalake?

Something like: notebook X issued a read on Deltalake at time T.

Use Case: This information will help me understand the lineage between datasets and associated notebooks involved in the lineages.

P.S: My deltalake is stored in ADLS (mounted in databricks)

Comment: I don't think it exists, but I wonder whether it could be built with a custom extension of the delta lake standalone: https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-standalone.html or even delta-rs (Rust API) https://docs.rs/deltalake/latest/deltalake/.

Comment: Alternatively, Delta lake already requires for concurrency that you have some trust/control of the writers for a table. Perhaps, if you have enough control of your readers, you could make them go through a logging API or library.

Answer (score -1):

As the definitive record of every change ever made to a table, the Delta Lake transaction log offers users a verifiable data lineage that is useful for governance, audit and compliance purposes. It can also be used to trace the origin of an inadvertent change or a bug in a pipeline back to the exact action that caused it.

> Users can run [DESCRIBE HISTORY](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#history) to see metadata around the changes that were made.

[image]

For more details, refer to [Diving Into Delta Lake: Unpacking The Transaction Log](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/08/21/diving-into-delta-lake-unpacking-the-transaction-log.html).

Comment: OP already acknowledged the write/table change logging. They asked about logging read queries.